# How would you build a small cyclotron (particle accelerator)?

Tags: particle-physics, experimental-physics, particle-detectors, technology, particle-accelerators

I heard Michio Kaku built a small cyclotron when he was young. I bought a book called "Principles of charged particle acceleration" where it explains the basic functioning of particle accelerators. What are the basic things you would need to build one (making it function is a complete different thing) without investing an insane amount of money? What steps would you follow to build one? I would like to use it to create Na22 and possibly make a positron detector, which I would also like to briefly know how to make one, as I have no clue where to start.

**PD:** I'm aware this is not something easy to do (I'll try to get some teachers at university to help me) and probably I will never even start to  build it, but I think it's something worth considering as it's a nice way to have real contact with particle physics, not just playing with the mathematics.

Comment: Is it easy? I would say... fairly, on the scale of modern industrial technology. At the beginning of the 20th century physicists had to learn from scratch how to build them with little insight into the theory, at first, and really no access to working high vacuum technology, at all. Today you can get the theory out of books on accelerator design (and you should read and understand it) and the vacuum components come out of the catalog. You can get yourself a machine shop and a good machinist and start building, if you want. The question would be why you would want to, in the first place?

Comment: @CuriousOne  I would like to use it to create Na22 isotopes, which emit positrons.

Comment: You can buy a 22Na source at http://www.imagesco.com/geiger/radioactive-sources.html#sources for about $100.

Comment: As a general piece of advice: never consider building something that is available for money from scratch. EVER. The people who are offering it to you are a) more experienced b) much better at it than you can hope to be and c) no matter how expensive the item seems to be, it will always be cheaper than what you are going to pay for the learning curve. If you want to learn how to build a cyclotron, you can become an employee of these folks: http://www.advancedcyclotron.com/cyclotron-solutions/. If you want to learn about real accelerators... go work for CERN.

Comment: If I recall right, the Rutgers physics department has a student-built cyclotron that is operational. Check out their web pages (rutgers.edu).

Comment: @CuriousOne 1. If something I've learnt in my life is that things you do yourself are more satisfying. Sure I can look at the solutions of problems but I prefer to figure the solution myself. Same with this. It's not the first time I build something that I could have bought and its so much fun. 2. I wish it was that easy to work in CERN.

Comment: I am not saying that learning to build an accelerator is not satisfying. I have done these things myself. The question is why you would want to waste your life on building a "Ye Olde Particle Accelerator", when you can help building the next high energy machine for real research... using the same amount of time from your one-time life? It is "that" easy to work at CERN. I did it. All you have to do is to join a research group that works with CERN, already. Again, you only have one life... and you are wasting it on what? Why not do the real thing, instead?

Comment: @CuriousOne you'll have to start somewhere. I don't think building it would take me more than a summer.

Comment: For what it's worth, Michio Kaku built a betatron. They're smaller, cheaper and easier to build yourself than a cyclotron.

Comment: @dukwon I think he built both and the one he used to photograph antimatter was a cyclotron. I'm not sure... but I dont think colliding electrons with sodium would produce Na22 so it makes more sense if it were a cyclotron (accelerates protons). Thanks for the comment though!

Comment: Where you start is in school by learning the theory and then you do an apprenticeship with a scientist who is right up there with the stars of the field. Kaku, by the way, is not a star scientist. He is a very flashy guy who works a lot for tv, but as far as physics is concerned you can forget about him. I am having a little bit of trouble with your motivation, anyway... first you want to make 22Na, I point out to you that you an buy it cheaply, then you want to be a do-it-yourselfer... none of this sounds like you are even borderline interested in science or real engineering.

Comment: @CuriousOne Why do you always have to be so demolishing in your answers? Is it that bad to try build something? Buy, buy, I'm really tired of this consumerist society. If I want to make Na22 is not for the pleasure of making sodium isotopes, is to give a utility to the machine. I don't care if its sodium, tritium or rho mesons, I just want to smash atoms like a little kid playing with his toys. You say I'd be wasting my life building one of these "Ye olde particle accelerator", well, what are your contributions to physics? What have you done "not wasting your time"? I'm tired of this.

Comment: I am simply trying to get you on the right path. Building a steam engine doesn't teach modern thermodynamics. Building a now 80 year old accelerator design doesn't teach high energy physics or even accelerator physics. None of this is for "little kids", by the way. Even a small toy machine will expose you to seriously dangerous electrical systems and radiation. What are my contributions to physics? I helped with the design of the LHC experiments and my hardware is deployed in one of the world's largest particle detectors. I was certainly not toying around, but now you are getting personal.

Comment: I'm not of the opinion that this is an engineering question, it appears to me to absolutely be experimental physics. My issue, however, is that it's basically asking for step-by-step instructions on how to build such an experiment and I don't think that's a suitable question for this Q&A site (i.e., this is a classic case of *too broad*).